# Front tire larger then back

Tags: tire, front

My front tire is 24×2.10 and my back is 24×1.95 should I leave them like that, or should the larger be in the back ?

Comment: What is your use case for this bicycle? Do you feel confident at speed, on descents, and while cornering? Do you feel like one tire is more grippy, or cushions the riding surface more? Would you like to change any of those characteristics?

Comment: If the parts fit the bicycle (i.e. are compatible and do not cause any damage to the bike or danger to the rider), and if they fit whatever riding you do with it, then there isn't much in the way of what you "should" mount. Some people might look at you funny, or insist for some reason or another (usually boiling down to aesthetics) that you "should" do as they say, but ultimately much of bicycling is personal preference. If these tires don't put you in danger and you prefer this arrangement for whatever reason, then it is what you "should" have.

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively common amongst mountain bikers.  A narrower faster rolling tyre in the rear and a wider grippier tyre in the front.

On road bikes you often see the opposite, a wider tyre for comfort in the rear and a narrow tyre for aerodynamics in the front.

As long as the tyres fit your bike and don't rub it's entirely up to you to run whatever combination suits your riding best.

Comment: I'm constrained to 2.1" at the back on my mtb. 2.3" on the front pairs will with that and gives more grip than both 2.1". I've also done the other way round on my tourer (28mm front, 32mm rear occasionally) and routinely on my hybrid (28 or 32mm front, 35mm rear)

Comment: ... If it's a general purpose useful bike (which is where I'm used to 1.95") my preference is to make the most of what you've got - wearing out is a compelling reason to change, but not much else is

Answer (score 1):

Joe Murray thinks the bigger tyre should be on the front too. Or he did when he was working with Kona in the 1980s and 90s